# XPath selection while excluding elements having certain attribute values

Tags: xpath, filter, attributes

My first post here - it's a great site and I will certainly do my best to give back as much as I can.

I have seen different manifestations of this following question; however my attempts to resolve don't appear to work.

Consider this simple tree:

```
<root>
    <div>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p>hello2</p>
        <p><span class="bad">hello3</span></p>
    </div>
</root>
```

I would like to come up with an XPath expression that will select all child nodes of "div", **except** for elements that have their "class" attribute equal to "bad".

Here is what I have tried:

```
/root/div/node()[not (@class='bad')]
```

... However this doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing here?

Cheers,
Isaac

Comment: @Isaac: This test `not(@class='bad')` will be true for all your `div` **childs**.

Comment: @Alejandro: That's the intention... I want my XPath expression to basically filter the entire tree and remove all elements having their "class" attribute equal to "bad".

Comment: xpath selects nodes -- it doesn't "remove" them.

Comment: I know. I'm using the XPath expression within an XSLT - copying all nodes from the source tree except for those having the class=bad attribute. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: /root/div/node() will return all of the <p> nodes along with the whitespace text nodes between them. Do you want the last <p> selected or not ? If you want the last <p>, but not it's contents ( <span class="bad" >...</span> ), then it's not an xpath selection problem : you need to filter with XSLT.

Comment: The best way in xslt is to use the identity template and add a special null production for  *[class='bad']

Comment: @Steven D. Majewski: Besides that the question is unclear, you can select any node with XPath expressions, as in `/root/div//*[not(@class='bad')]` wich select all descendant elements not having a class attribute with 'bad' as value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing your XPath [here](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) with the provided XML document, the XPath seems to be indeed selecting all child nodes that do not have an attribute `class="bad"` - these are all the `<p>` elements in the document.

You will note that the only child node that has such an attribute is the `<span>`, which indeed does not get selected.

Are you expecting the `p` node surrounding your `span` not to be selected?

Comment: Shalom Oded,

Interesting link - thanks. Now, the example I gave above is a minimal representation of a huge XML tree I'm working with. Trying to execute the same XPath expression using Java doesn't seem to work.

The "p" element should be selected; indeed, all I wanted was for that "span" element to be thrown out.

I should investigate further as to why my XPath expression doesn't work for my specific problem; will post here if I come up with anything useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Isaac: We are trying to tell you that `span` element will **never** be selected because it's not a child of `div` but a child of `p`.

Comment: I think you have a typo somewhere in your first sentence, because this `Child nodes means all child nodes, whatever their depth, not just direct descendants` is wrong.

Comment: @Alejandro: well DUH. Good catch. Can't believe I wasted so much time because of a missing slash... Thank you!

Comment: FYI: link seems to be broken

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with XPath in a Java program I'm writing. If you want to select the nodes that don't have class="bad" (i.e. the `<span>` nodes, but not the surrounding `<p>` nodes), you could use:

```
/root/div/descendant::*[not (@class='bad')]
```

Otherwise, if you want to select the

nodes that don't have a child with class='bad', you can use something like the following:

```
/root/div/p/*[not (@class='bad')]/..
```

the `..` part selects the immediate parent node.

Answer (score 0):

The identity transform just matches and copies everything:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But you add a null transform that more specifically matches the pattern you want to exclude:

```
 <xsl:template match="span[@class='bad']" />
```

( you can also add a priority attrib if you want to be more explicit about which one has precedence. )

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Isaac!

I'd try this:

```
/root/div/*[./*[@class != "bad"]]
```

this ought to select all child elements (`*`) of the `div` element that do not have a descendant element with a `class` attribute that equals `bad`.

**Edit:**

As per @Alejandros comment:

```
/root/div/*[not(*/@class "bad")]
```

Comment: @FK82: I think that a more proper path for what you are trying is `/root/div/*[not(*/@class = "bad")]`. Do note that @class != "bad" will be false for those elements not having @class...

Comment: Well I tried `/root/div/node()[not (descendant-or-self::*[@class="bad"])]` when I thought that was what he wanted, but he seems to be saying in the comments above that he wants to include the outer <p> containing the <span class="bad">, but filter out the inner <span class="bad"> .

Comment: @Steven D. Majewski: that doesn't make sense at all. I figure there is nothing to add then.

Comment: @FK82: Again, `@class and @class != "bad"` will be false for those element having not @class, but you want to exclude only those having @class equal to "bad". So `@class="bad"` is true for those you want to exclude, then `not(@class="bad")` is true for those you want to keep: `!=` and `=` operator are not reversible for node set comparison. And last, starting a relative path expression with `.` is almost never useful.